# GraphQL subscriptions with dynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, subscription

I have a problem figuring out how to update a data shown in the client based on changes in the database. Just a basic dashboard with real-time data. I am using GraphQL and dynamoDB for this project.

The data itself is coming through IoT, and I am redirecting them to a dynamoDB table. All I want is to update the dashboard whenever new data enters in the dynamoDB table.

I heard about AppSync and Amplify, and that they have subscriptions already built in. But these subscriptions only work when a mutation is triggered. And thats not what I want, I don't want to fire any mutation, just to trigger an updated when I receive new data.

I also know there are DynamoDB streams, but I really don't want to use them because I already started using Amplify. (the wiring would be terrible)

Is there any other approach to this use case? Without using DynamoDB streams..
Am I missing something from Amplify/AppSync, and there is a way to do it with these frameworks?

Thank You all for the responses/suggestions.

Comment: Without a mutation call, it's impossible for a AppSync subscription to receive a notification. @aws_subscribe is to pick a source of notifications, and it only accepts Mutation.

Comment: Since you're using AppSync, I'd suggest you create a mutation for updating DynamoDb instead of using aws-sdk for a direct update. With the mutation call, you receive notifications.